# Pandas, how to filter a df to get unique entries?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
ID  type value
1   A    8
2   A    5
3   B    11
4   C    12
5   D    1
6   D    22
7   D    13
```

I want to filter the dataframe so that I have a unique occurrence of "type" attrybute (e.g. A appears only once), and if there are more rows that have the same value for "type" I want to choose the one with higher value. 
I want to get something like:

```
ID  type value
1   A    8
3   B    11
4   C    12
6   D    22
```

How do I do this with pandas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

one way is to sort the dataframe and then take the first after a groupby.

```
# first way
sorted = df.sort_values(['type', 'value'], ascending = [True, False])

first = sorted.groupby('type').first().reset_index()
```

another way does not necessarily take only the first one, so potentially it would keep all IDs corresponding to the same maximum (and not take just 1 of them)

```
# second way
grouped = df.groupby('type').agg({'value': max}).reset_index()
grouped = grouped.set_index(['type','value'])

second = grouped.join(df.set_index(['type', 'value']))
```

example:

data

```
ID  type    value
1   A   8
2   A   5
3   B   11
4   C   12
5   D   1
6   D   22
7   D   13
8   D   22
```

first method results in

```
type  ID  value
A   1      8
B   3     11
C   4     12
D   6     22
```

second method keeps ID=8

```
            ID
type value    
A    8       1
B    11      3
C    12      4
D    22      6
     22      8
```

(you can `reset_index()` again here if you don't like the multiindex)

Comment: Fantastic answer. Still one problem. In reality my idexes are the IDs and they are unique identifier string like 'M_001' how can I restore those indexes? Saving it as a extra column and assigning them as a index afterwards?

Comment: from above, I would do `second.reset_index().set_index('ID')`

Answer (score 8):

```
df[['type', 'value']].drop_duplicates(subset=['type'])
```

This works generally, if you would have more columns, you can select the interested columns, in our case we chose all, 'type', 'value'.

Answer (score 2):

Use groupby "type" and grab only the first object - 
df.groupby("type").first()

Comment: Nice! In this way I loose the ID. How can I restore the previous layout?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer my way. Because groupby will create new df. You will get unique values. But tecnically this will not filter your df, this will create new one. My way will keep your indexes untouched, you will get the same df but without duplicates.

```
df = df.sort_values('value', ascending=False)
# this will return unique by column 'type' rows indexes
idx = df['type'].drop_duplicates().index
#this will return filtered df
df.loc[idx,:]
```

Comment: If you could give some verbal information your answer will be much richer.

Comment: In addition to what @scriptmonster said, when answering old questions with an accepted answer, it's especially useful to explain why your approach is preferred over that answer.

Comment: Thank you for your advices.